# How to render chrome extension UI depending on data?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am creating my first chrome extension, i need to render the extension HTML once the extension is loaded depending on some data that i pre-created manually, no fetch from any external server, i have created all necessary assets of the extension and now i need to use `popup.js` to create the extension markup

`popup.js`

```
  const body = document.getElementById('body') // extenstion HTML body
  const bookList = document.getElementById('book-list')

  body.addEventListener('load', async () => {
     let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active:true,currentWindow:true})

     chrome.scripting.executeScript({
         target: { tabId: tab.id },
         function: renderExtension,
     });

  });

 function renderExtension() {
   chrome.storage.sync.get("books", ({ books}) => {
     books.forEach(book=> {
       bookList.innerHTML += `<input placeholder=${book.name}>`
     })
   })
 }
```

and in `background.js`

```
let books = [
   //books objects
]

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ books});

});
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, i get nothing rendered in the extension, it is the my first extension so may be i am missing something and i need to know what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: @wOxxOm unfortunatley, it doesn't work

Comment: @wOxxOm it is the same code and i did some changes to `renderExtension` function to use `books` without chrome storage, and i defined the `books` variable in `popup.js` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chrome.scripting.executeScript runs the script in the active web page in the tab, but the popup is a separate page with a chrome-extension:// URL shown in a separate window, completely unrelated to the web page. The popup.js script you load in your popup.html runs in that window so you should simply access its `window`, `document`, and DOM directly.

There's also no need for the background script and storage, just put the data in **popup.js**:

```js
const books = [
  {name: 'foo'},
  {name: 'bar'},
];

document.getElementById('book-list').innerHTML =
  books.map(b => `<input placeholder=${b.name}>`).join('');
```

There's no need to wait for `load` either, just put your script at the end of body in **popup.html**:

```html
<body>
  <div id="book-list"></div>
  <script src=popup.js></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Does that also mean we can use `append` using `document.getElementById`?